Showing that $V^*\rightarrow .^*(V^*)$ is an exact functor.
I am studying the paper "Koszul duality patterns in representation theory" by BGS and have a question. First the setup: Let $k$ be a semisimple ring and $V$ a k-module. We define the module dual as $V^*=Hom_k(V,k)$ which is a right k-module by $(fa(v))=(f(v))a$ for all $f \in V^*,v \in V, a\in k$.
Moreover, for all right k-modules $W$ we define the dual as $.^*(W)=Hom_k(W,k)$ by $(ag)(w)=a(g(w))$ for all $g\in .^*W, w \in W, a \in k$.
I am trying to prove the statement in chapter 2.7 that $V \cong .^*(V^*)$ is an isomorphism for all filitely generated k-modules $V$. I have already proven that this isomorphism holds for free, finitely generated k-modules. Now I want to deduce that it also holds for non free finitely generated modules.
My idea is that if the functor $f:V \rightarrow .^*(V^*)$ is exact one can construct a free resolution onto $V$ with free, finitely generated modules. If $f$ is exact this would imply that by applying $f$ we would have an isomorphism everywhere on the projective resolution and thus this would also imply the isomorphism $V\cong .^*(V^*)$. Now here is my problem:
It is easy to see that $V \rightarrow V^*$ is contravariant (I hope this is the right definition. With contravariant I mean that any short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow M \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$ of k-modules implies that $0 \rightarrow N^* \rightarrow M^* \rightarrow L^* \rightarrow 0$ is also exact). But I am unsure on how to proceed further.
Does it suffice to show that $V^*\rightarrow .^*(V^*)$ is also contravariant? If this suffices, than this is true as $V^*$ is a right k-module and thus injective, right? I am also unsure why we define $V^*$ as a right $k$-module it seems to me like this is just making it more complicated.
Thank you for any help!

Can you show that both functors are additive? After all, over a semisimple ring every short exact sequence splits, so....

@JyrkiLahtonen yes the functor is exact, but I am unsure how that helps me.. I have found this approach then link , bit that doesn’t seem right..

Have you seen the usual mapping from a vector space to its double dual? That is very "natural", and should give something extra. I'm a bit rusty, but it feels like that would yield a chain map from your resolution to the double dual. Then you can use the fact that the natural map is an isomorphism on f.g. free modules.

And about the last paragraph: $V^$ is usually not a left $k$-module. So you have two functors $V\mapsto V^$ from $k$-mod to mod$-k$ and then an another functor $M\mapsto {}^*M$ from mod$-k$ to $k-$mod. You need to compose them to get a functor from one category to itself.

@JyrkiLahtonen Sorry in my first comment I meant that the functor is additive.  I have used the natural map from the module to its double dual to show that the isomorphism holds for free f.g modules. But I still need $f$ to be exact to use it on the resolution, no?

A point in my first comment was that when all short exact sequences split, additivity implies exactness.
